# Цикл который переходит по ссылкам продуктов, собирает данные и выходит

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Всем привет, мне нужна помощь! мне нужен цикл который зайдет на страницу продукта, соберет данные и выйдет, потом к следующему продукту и так далее. При том что этот цикл будет в цикле который у меня уже есть. Если кто может помогите, за ранее спасибо!))

```
webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', service_args=['--ssl-protocol=any', '--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/s?k=galaxy+s10&qid=1564815305&ref=sr_pg_2")

page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
# print(soup.prettify())
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)



page_links=[]
links=[]
name=[]
product_price=[]


var=0
while True:
    while True: #цикл кликает по продуктм и выходит но только первый продукт!
        product=driver.find_element_by_class_name('s-search-results')
        time.sleep(2)
        product.find_element_by_class_name('a-text-normal').click()
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "a-text-normal")))
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
#         driver.back() это не сработало 
        continue

    driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-last').click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "a-last")))
    var+=1
    if var == 3:
        driver.close()
```

Comment: А что именно у Вас не получается? Мне непонятна суть Вашего вопросаю

Comment: Выше код листает страницы мне нужно добавить в нем цикл который по очереди зайдет в страницу продуктов спарсит и выйдет.